# Django minimize json in JsonResponse

Tags: python, json, django, jsonresponse

Is there a way to minimize a json in JsonResponse?
By minimize I mean removing spaces etc.

Thanks to this I can save around 100KB on my server ;).

Example:

I have a json:

```
{"text1": 1324, "text2": "abc", "text3": "ddd"}
```

And I want to achieve something like this:

```
{"text1":1324,"text2":"abc","text3":"ddd"}
```

Now creating response looks like that:

```
my_dict = dict()
my_dict['text1'] = 1324
my_dict['text2'] = 'abc'
my_dict['text3'] = 'ddd'
return JsonResponse(my_dict, safe=False)
```

Comment: Removing spaces from where keys, values or both?

Comment: Between them, key and values can't be changed. I added an example.

Comment: I believe `JsonResponse` will always space key value pairs like that.

Comment: pass the raw value `json.dumps(separators=(',', ':'))`

Comment: What a shame. How about creating json response manually by HttpResponse and json.dumps? There will be spaces between keys and values using a dict?

Comment: @SzymonBarylak That's exactly what I was thinking!

Comment: @SzymonBarylak Let me see if I can get it to do that in any other way.

Answer (score 2):

If you do this in enough places you could create your own JsonResponse like (mostly ripped from [django source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/response.py)):

```
class JsonMinResponse(HttpResponse):
    def __init__(self, data, encoder=DjangoJSONEncoder, safe=True, **kwargs):
        if safe and not isinstance(data, dict):
            raise TypeError('In order to allow non-dict objects to be '
                'serialized set the safe parameter to False')
        kwargs.setdefault('content_type', 'application/json')
        data = json.dumps(data, separators = (',', ':')), cls=encoder)
        super(JsonMinResponse, self).__init__(content=data, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

`HTTPResponse` allows us to return data in the format we specify using separators with `json.dumps`

```
HttpResponse(json.dumps(data, separators = (',', ':')), content_type = 'application/json')
```